# handler or timer android

Tags: java, android, timer, handler

i'm tryin' to display a msg every 1 min!! non stop! i found exemple that display the msg just one time after a fixed delay!! can you help how can set it?? or if using timer is better how it works i need an exemple!!

```
public class TimertestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

      @Override   
      public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {   
        super.onCreate(icicle);   
        setContentView(R.layout.main);  
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(
            new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    afficher();
                }
            }, 1000L);

      }   

      public void afficher()
      {
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                     "test",
                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you found a solution that works for you, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this code -

```
public class TimertestActivity extends Activity {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            afficher();
        }
    };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

      @Override   
      public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {   
        super.onCreate(icicle);   
        setContentView(R.layout.main);  
        runnable.run();
      }   

      public void afficher()
      {
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                     "test",
                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
      }
}
```

Comment: done but i just need ur help for sthing i want to call another function that insert values in database if i launch the function alone it work but in the time it doesn't work can u help me plzzz?

Comment: solved thnx that i meant is to excute 2 fuction not just afficher()!! so i just called the second function simpally! thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

```
// Timer using Handler

private final int SPLASH_TIME = 3000;

// Handling splash timer.
private void startSplashTimer() {
    new Handler().postDelayed(
    new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this,MainActivity.class));
    }
}, SPLASH_TIME);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TimerTask` for this.But when your device goes sleep it will not working so i think you can use `AlarmManager` for this.
Anyway refer [this link](http://thedevelopersinfo.wordpress.com/2009/10/18/scheduling-a-timer-task-to-run-repeatedly/) for `TimerTask` ,

AlarmManager code,

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) Context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), interval, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: But in alarm manager you cant show toast message.It will show new activity.but this will helpful to you.