# Android - IntentService - sendBroadcast from custom method

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

I have an intent service in my app that is called from the main thread. The intent service is started upon clicking on a button. Once started, the service connects to the server and retrieves information.

I want to send broadcast to the activity **once the data is retrieved**. If I send it from the onHandleIntent(), the data might not be retrieved yet.

Can't I send the broadcast from the method that retrieves the data? If not, any alternatives?

code sample:

```
onHandleIntent()
{

    myMethod();

  //Here where it is expected to send the broadcast
             Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
             broadcastIntent.setAction("com.example.intent.action.MESSAGE_PROCESSED");
             broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
             broadcastIntent.putExtra("TAG",Message);
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

}

MyMethod()
{
 //Retrieving data from server, which returns Message.

 //Here Where I want to send broadcast (Message is ready)
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are u using AsynTask for Server retrives info ?

Comment: no I'm connecting directly from the intentService (it's working in the background). How would that make a difference?

Comment: IntentService itself run in background thread.Plz give some code snippets so that we can figureout what u r trying to do

Comment: I know, my problem is that I want to return results the the main thread once the data is retrieved, but I'm not managing to use sendBroadcast() but from the onHandleIntent().

Comment: Posting some code will be better.

Comment: but what's exactly your problem? You dont know how to handle the broadcast from your activity?

Comment: @berserk I included sample code.
on the activity side it's fine, it's the when I want to send the broadcast (I need it once the data is retrieved from server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use a handler/runnable combo to act as a timer, so that you check whether the value is null or not before sending the broadcast. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678658/handler-or-timer-android) for how to do that.

edit:
It would look like this:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            sendBroadcast();
        }
};


onHandleIntent()
{
    myMethod();
    runnable.run();
}

MyMethod()
{
 //Retrieving data from server, which returns Message.

 //Here Where I want to send broadcast (Message is ready)
}


sendBroadcast(){
// If your value is still null, run the runnable again
if (Message == null){
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
}
else{
//Here where it is expected to send the broadcast
             Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
             broadcastIntent.setAction("com.example.intent.action.MESSAGE_PROCESSED");
             broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
             broadcastIntent.putExtra("TAG",Message);
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following in your activity class:

1- Create a BroadcastReceiver

```
private class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver             
  @Override    
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


  //Get your server response
  String server_response = intent.getExtras().getString("TAG");

  //Do your work
  }
}
```

2- Create an object in your activity (as a member of the activity)

```
MyBroadcastReceiver mReceiver= new MyBroadcastReceiver ();
```

3- Register it in your `onResume()` method and deregister it in your `onPause()` method.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("com.example.intent.action.MESSAGE_PROCESSED");

    registerReceiver(mChatReceiver, filter);
}
```

---

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}
```

That should be enough!, Hope it helps!

Comment: @zozelfefo can you please explain how does this solve the issue? because the problem is in sending the broadcast not receiving it

Comment: mm This is how you should receive your broadcast in your activity. Isn't that what you wanted? to receive the broadcast sent from your `IntentService` to your `Activity`.

Comment: no, my problem is that I want to send the broadcast after retrieving data from the server (inside the intentService), but am supposed to send it from onHandleIntent(), I'm getting null on the receiver side, because when sending the broadcast, the data is not retrieved yet

Comment: Maybe then your problem might be that you are launching another thread inside your `IntentService`, that's why  you are not receiving the server response. Post your `myMethod` method in order to check it.