# how to move to another activity without clicking anything

Tags: android

in android studio how to make an empty activity stay onscreen for just 5 seconds and then automatically proceed to the next activity. I just want the first activity to show a loading icon and after few seconds it should automatically proceed to the next activity.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678658/handler-or-timer-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [handler or timer android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678658/handler-or-timer-android)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to display an activity automatically after 5 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304035/how-to-display-an-activity-automatically-after-5-seconds)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to move from the current activity(splash) to MainActivity after 3 seconds represented as 3000 in ms. U run this piece of code inside your onCreate method

**Kotlin**

```
Handler().postDelayed({
        startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
        finish()
    }, 3000)
```

**Java**

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a hadler defining the source and target activity, you can define the time to open the target Activity for 5 seconds define 5000 milliseconds

```
private int FIVE_SECONDS = 5000;

...
...

new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
        startActivity(new Intent(<Source Activity>.this, <Target Activity>.class));
        finish();//Use this if you want to finish the currrent Activity
    }, FIVE_SECONDS);
```